# HVAC is not blowing. Is it most likely the blower motor?

Tags: ac, hvac

I have a 1998 Buick Park Avenue (standard not ultra).  Recently the heating and air stopped blowing.  It acts normal in every other way (lights and indicators work as normal) but I am not getting any blowing at all no matter the setting.

I have been assuming that the issue is blower motor (which is remarkaly easy to replace at least in my buick).

Am I correct to assume that is the problem?  Once I remove the blower motor is there an easy way to test it to verify that it is bad?

Thanks.

Seth

Comment: To clarify, do you *hear* air blowing that isn't coming out of any vents? When you switch the fan speed to maximum do you hear absolutely nothing, no change?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you've checked/changed the fuse first?

If the blower motor is easy to get at, I would go and pulling the connector off and check that you're actually getting power to the motor and only then pull the motor if you've confirmed that you do. It wouldn't be the first time that it's actually the fan switch or something upstream from the blower motor that's gone wrong.

Comment: Tim, thanks for your answers.  Total newbie here...so to check that I remove the wires and then use a multimeter...set it to DC 10 and touch the two leads to the wire connectors...is that basically it?

Comment: You want to set it to something that covers at least 15V DC, but yes, that's the principle. One of the connectors is likely to be the ground connector so you might have to identify that first by cross-checking the various connectors (if you have more than two) and then measure the other connectors against ground while you move/turn the fan switchs.

Comment: @Mark Johnson: I seen that too...nasty.

Answer (score 3):

It's fairly common for the fan switch to go bad. You might be able to connect 12v directly to the fan motor and see if it runs, if there are only two wires going to the fan. But there are more than two wires and you hook 12v to the wrong ones, you could do some damage to an otherwise good fan.

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct to assume that the problem is the blower motor before first checking

1. Fuses
2. The blower motor relay
3. The blower motor resistor

If all of these components are in working order then the next thing I would try would be the blower motor itself.